# What is an example of quadratic number field in which $17$ is a prime element?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for a imaginary quadratic number field in which $17$ is a prime element.
For example, in $\Bbb{Q}(i)$, $17$ is not prime element.
$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$ was in vain.

Once imaginary quadratic field is given, I can check whether $17$ is a prime element or not by calculating residue ring, but I cannot find what the imaginary quadratic field is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-19})$, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-43})$ $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-67})$ work.  I just searched the Heegner numbers, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=JacobiSymbol%5B%7B-1%2C+-2%2C+-3%2C+-7%2C+-11%2C+-19%2C+-43%2C+-67%2C+-163%7D%2C17%5D)

Comment: Isn’t it enough to find a quadratic field that has unique factorization and for which 17 is not a norm?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ with $n\bmod 17$ not a square